# Send broadcast with extra `Bundle` using adb

Tags: android, adb

I need to send the broadcast using adb. The broadcast `Intent` must contain extra `PersistableBundle`.
Having searched thee [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#IntentSpec), I find no such thing. Is it possible?

The documentation describes all the Intent extras (like Strings, longs, etc.), but no `Bundle`.

Comment: You cannot create arbitrary `Parcelable` objects from the command line, which AFAIK includes `PersistableBundle`.

Comment: Shouldn't `am` tool (Activity Manager) be able, at least in theory, to handle creation of `Parcelable`?

Comment: IMHO, that would be impractical. You are asking for a set of command-line arguments that could define an instance of an arbitrary class with arbitrary fields, where those fields are of arbitrary classes with arbitrary fields, and so on down the object hierarchy. And, even if `am` could do that in theory, in practice, it doesn't. `am` is designed for lightweight scenarios. If `am` is essential to you, replace the `PersistableBundle` with a JSON string or something.